# How to use Nintegrate in mathematica whose integrand contains elements from a 1d array that need to be accessed by index

Tags: integration, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

[image: Integral]

where the issue lies with variables like F since it is defined as 
F[x_, y_] := f[x, y]/(2*Cto[Norm[x]]*Cto[Norm[y]]) and Cto[x_] := C_t[[Round[x]]]
where C_t is a 1d array and x and y are two vector and I need to access the element of C_t corresponding to the integer of the magnitude of x for example. However, this gives me the following errors when evaluating the integral:

```
Ci = Flatten[Import["Downloads/ctjulien.txt", "table"]]
Cp = Flatten[Import["Downloads/clphiphi.txt", "table"]]
Subscript[C, t] = Flatten[Import["Downloads/ctobs.txt", "table"]]



Lp[a_] := 1052*{Cos[a], Sin[a]}
vL[L_] := {L, 0}
l[l1_, \[CapitalPhi]1_] := 
 l1*{Cos[\[CapitalPhi]1], Sin[\[CapitalPhi]1]}
Cii[x_] := Ci[[Round[x]]]
f[x_, y_] := Cii[Norm[x]]*Dot[x + y, x] + Cii[Norm[y]]*Dot[x + y, y]
Cto[x_] := Subscript[C, t][[Round[x]]]
F[x_, y_] := f[x, y]/(2*Cto[Norm[x]]*Cto[Norm[y]])
Cpp[x_] := Cp[[Round[x]]]

NIntegrate[l1*F[l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]],{L,0}-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]]]*F[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p],{L,0}-Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]]*(Dot[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p],Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]]]*If[Norm[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]]]<=2900,Cpp[Norm[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]]]],0]*f[-{L,0}+l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]],{L,0}-Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]]+Dot[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p],Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]-l[{L,0}-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]],\[CapitalPhi]]]*If[Norm[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]-l[{L,0}-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]],\[CapitalPhi]]]<=2900,Cpp[Norm[Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]-l[{L,0}-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]],\[CapitalPhi]]]],0]*f[-l[l1,\[CapitalPhi]],{L,0}-Lp[\[CapitalPhi]p]]),{\[CapitalPhi],-Pi,Pi},{\[CapitalPhi]p,-Pi,Pi},{l1,2,3000}]
```

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't anywhere near an answer yet, but it is a start. Watch out for Subscript and greek characters and use those appropriately when you test this.

If you insert in front of your code

```
Ci =Table[RandomInteger[{1,10}],{3000}];
Cp =Table[RandomInteger[{1,10}],{3000}];
Ct =Table[RandomInteger[{1,10}],{3000}];
```

then you can try to test your code without having your data files present.

If you then test your code you get a stream of "The expression Round[Abs[2+L]] cannot be used as a part" but if you instead insert in front of your code `L=2` or some other integer assignment then that error goes away

If you use `NIntegrate[yourlongexpression...]` then you get a stream of "Round[Sqrt[Abs[l1 Cos[phi]]^2+Abs[l1 Sin[phi]]^2 cannot be used as a part" If you instead use `fun[phi_?NumericQ, phip_?NumericQ, l1_?NumericQ]:=yourlongexpression;
NIntegrate[fun[phi,phip,l1]...]` then that error goes away.

If you use `Table[fun[phi,phip,l1],{phi,-Pi,Pi,Pi/2},{phip,-Pi,Pi,Pi/2},{l1,2,10}]` instead of your integral and you look carefully at the output then you should see the word `List` appearing a number of times. That means you have `somelist[[0]]` somewhere in your code and Mathematica subscripts all start with 1, not with 0 and that has to be tracked down and fixed.

That is probably the first three or four levels of errors that need to found and fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Now the only errors I am getting are: NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small and The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more \
than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease \
monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations.